# Monitor Subwoofer suggestions (economic)

Tags: gear, prices, monitors, bass, acoustics

Hey Im l@@kin to invest some money in reference monitors and a sub.

Can anybody drop some suggestions for me?  My price range is limited to about 600 american dollars and I have a discount available to me which can knock off a few bucks.  All I know right now is to stay away from Rockit 5's.

This would be for editing and basic mixing once I sound panel and tune my room.
The room is a regular size bedroom.

Comment: Consider building your own sub - you can spend more on quality drivers by cutting out the retail up-price on the case, etc.  Added bonus of learning more about loudspeakers in the process. 

Answer (score 3):

Blue Sky has two entry level 2.1 systems in that price range. The [eXo2](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/eXo2/) is $449, and [MediaDesk 2.1](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/MediaDesk2m2/) is $795. They aren't the most pro things out there (you connect everything to the sub, and the sub powers itself and the satellites), but they are Blue Sky, and they are better than the KRK stuff.  Although, the KRKs aren't terrible for the price...

Stay away from the M Audio entry level stuff though (BX5a). Very hyped low end, muffled highs.

eXo2:
[image]

MediaDesk 2.1:
[image]

Comment: Its funny that you mention these, I did some shopping around and they seem perfect for me.

Comment: +1 to Blue Sky products... great for the money!

Comment: yep, my school has bluesky products and I used to love working on them